# How long to review and approved an Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, submit

Did anyone know how long an Blackberry application to be review and approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little clarification in the question would be useful.  Approve for what?

I presume you are talking about BB World Approval, and there the answer is "It depends".  Minimum will be a few days.  At times it has taken my applications 3 weeks or more.  As I understand it, it depends on what else they are working on.  From memory, the FAQs give an expected time and I think that is the guidelines that they are working towards.